# Can't push existing git repository to new TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm really desparing. I just installed a Team Foundation Server to move from an older simple git server to it. So now I'm having many branches on my old git server which I'd like to migrate to the TFS but actually I can't.

I created the project in the TFS, tried to clone it into Visual Studio and wanted to push my old files with `git push --mirror origin`. Before I set the TFS git repo to my remote origin.

For the TFS it worked, I had two branches there which I had in my old git as well. But Visual Studio didn't notice that I have these. I don't know what I did wrong.

Is there an easy way to migrate an existing git server to the TFS? With all branches that existed before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone old repo:

```
    git clone {our_old_repo}
```

Pull in remote branches, for each branch execute (or make a powershell script  if you have too many branches for manual labor):

```
    git branch {branchname} origin/{branchname}
```

Re-target to new repo location:

```
    git remote set-url origin {your_new_repo}
```

Push all code to new repo:

```
    git push -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a fetch. Visual Studio has no way of knowing that it needs to sync up with the remote repo unless you tell it.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but actually I didn't come that far. I just tried to recreate the project in TFS and after connecting to it from Visual Studio all of my commits automatically have been pushed to the TFS and I got all branches I need. But it seems like VS is still using the other git server due to the visibility of all remote branches which aren't on the TFS but on the old git server. Is there a reason to get rid of the old git server or to "deactivate" it?